# Где хранить middleware функции, как называть файлы. Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mvc, express

Я пытаюсь вникнуть в MVC паттерн, и все никак не могу понять структуру каталогов, где и что хранится.
Я читал много статей по этому поводу и все еще трудно все понять. Начнем с название файлов в каталогах, я не понимаю почему например в папке `controller` называют файлы index**Controllers**.js, а в папке `routes` не называют index**Router** так же как и в `models`, или это не имеет значение? Разве это не приводит потом к путанице, что за файл открыт, когда в редакторе открыт `index.js` из `models`, `index.js` из `routes` и `indexControllers.js` из `controller`. Из-за одинакового названия файлов не всегда понятно с чем мы работаем.
Не правильнее было бы называть файлы как: `indexRouter.js`, `indexModels.js` и `indexControllers.js`?

---

А теперь что касается `middleware`, где должны находится функции? В каком каталоге? Как правильнее называть функции?
Допустим сейчас у меня есть что-то такое:

```js
indexRouter.use('/', (req, res, next) =>
{
    let langGet = req.query.lang;
    let langCookie = req.language?.substr(0, 2);

    let lang = langAccess.find(lang => lang == langGet) || langAccess.find(lang => lang == langCookie) || 'en';

    if (langGet != lang)
    {
        let newSeach = new URLSearchParams(req._parsedUrl.search);
            newSeach.set('lang', lang);

        res.redirect(`?${newSeach.toString()}`);
    }
    else
    {
        next();
    }
});
```

Я это применял к каждому роуту, который мне был необходим, но получалось много повторения кода, что не правильно.
Как я понимаю и как мне подсказали, это является `middleware` и это можно или правильнее сказать - нужно вынести в отдельную функцию, но как ее назвать? `checkLangMiddleware`? А где она должна или может храниться? Создавать папку `middleware` и в ней `checkLangMiddleware.js`?

А где должен он применяться? В `app.js` что-то вроде этого?:

```js
app.use('/', [checkLangMiddleware], indexRouter);
```

Или же как я понимаю в `routes/indexRouter.js`:

```js
router.use('/', checkLangMiddleware);
// ...
router.get('/', ...)
```

---

А где нужно/правильнее хранить другие функции, которые могут использоваться в `models`, `controllers` или в `app.js`?

Comment: Попробуйте изучить [Nest.js](https://nestjs.com/) , как раз познакомитесь с строгой типизацией, MVC паттерном и сможете поработать с уже готовой экосистемой

Answer (score 0):

Назовите каталог helpers. А миделваре ваш CheckLanguageHelper.

PS. Мое мнение. Прошу не холиварить и добавить ответ. Если у вас сообственное мнение по данному вопросу

Comment: Почему именно helpers, что еще должно к этому относиться?

Comment: Другие мидлеваре например.  Auth... Logg ..